# Redefining symbol midway through a document

Tags: math-mode, macros, pdftex, symbols

I am trying to have one command (`\phi`) draw two different symbols (`\varphi` and regular `\phi`) in the same document.

I have tried this with the below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\newcommand{\oldphi}{\phi}
\renewcommand{\phi}{\varphi}

\begin{document}
$\phi$
\renewcommand{\phi}{\oldphi}
$\phi$
\end{document}
```

But this wont compile (with pdftex or TexMaker), it seem like it gets stuck in a loop and wont create a pdf, but I can't see why?

Or is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Yes: using \phi` when you want it, and `\varphi``  when it  is the one you need.

Comment: @Bernard I know that's the simplest way to do it really, but it would mean writing way to many extra letters :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `\let`, it works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\let\oldphi=\phi
\let\phi=\varphi 

\begin{document}

$\phi$

\let\phi=\oldphi
$\phi$

\let\phi=\varphi 
$\phi$

\let\phi=\oldphi
$\phi$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! I had just reached the same conclusion below, thanks!

Comment: Oh! I see. Great minds think together! :o)

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this myself using `\let` and so post this for posterity.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\let\oldphi\phi
\let\phi\varphi

\begin{document}
$\phi$
\let\phi\oldphi
$\phi$
\end{document}
```

My understanding is that `\newcommand{\x}{\y}` simply replaces "`\a`" with "`\b`" so can become circular, whereas `\let\a\b` actually sets `\a` to the value of `\b`, so resolves any self-referencing issues.